# Change the position of label and select Tag of form columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script and i want to change the position of the  and  Tag to switch thier places (For my RTL language). I want the  Tag to be on the right side, and the  Tag to be at the left side of the form.

Here's what i **have**:

[image]

What i **want** is:

[image]

Here's Some code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return false;">
    <fieldset>
    <div id="userIdInputContainer" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="userId">משתמש</label>
            <div class="controls inline-inputs">
                <select id="userId" name="userId"></select>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="filterCustomerIdTEInputContainer" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="filterCustomerIdTE">לקוח</label>
            <div class="controls inline-inputs">
                <select id="filterCustomerIdTE" name="filterCustomerIdTE"></select>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="projectIdInputContainer" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="projectId">פרויקט</label>
            <div id="parentProjectIdTE" class="controls inline-inputs">
                <select id="projectId" name="projectId"></select>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="categoryIdInputContainer" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="categoryId">סוג עבודה</label>
            <div class="controls inline-inputs">
                <select id="categoryId" name="categoryId"></select>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="descriptionInputContainer" class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="description">תיאור</label>
            <div class="controls inline-inputs">
                <textarea class="input-xlarge" id="description" rows="3"><#= _.escape(item.get('description') || '') #></textarea>
                <span class="help-inline"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Click on the "הוספת רשומה" blue button at the left to see the form.

Here is a the code of a **[bootstrap.min.css](https://www.oboom.com/STUT38WR/bootstrap.min.css)** (click to download) that handle the css parameters for the form:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label{float:none;width:auto;padding-top:0;text-align:left}.form-horizontal .controls{margin-left:0}.form-horizontal .control-list{padding-top:0}.form-horizontal .form-actions{padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px}.media .pull-left,.media .pull-right{display:block;float:none;margin-bottom:10px}.media-object{margin-right:0;margin-left:0}.modal{top:10px;right:10px;left:10px}
```

And the code of **[bootstrap-responsice.min.css](https://www.oboom.com/3ABL5DIO/bootstrap-responsive.min.css)** (click to download):

```
.control-label{float:left;width:160px;padding-top:5px;text-align:right}.form-horizontal .controls{*display:inline-block;*padding-left:20px;margin-left:180px;*margin-left:0}.form-horizontal .controls:first-child{*padding-left:180px}.form-horizontal .help-block{margin-bottom:0}.form-horizontal input+.help-block,.form-horizontal select+.help-block,.form-horizontal textarea+.help-block,.form-horizontal .uneditable-input+.help-block,.form-horizontal .input-prepend+.help-block,.form-horizontal .input-append+.help-block{margin-top:10px}.form-horizontal .form-actions{padding-left:180px}table{max-width:100%;background-color:transparent;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}
```

I tried several css/html ways to implement it but without success.

Comment: show us the javascript code you have tried

Comment: I have add to post a link to the script

Comment: why can't you just interchange the position of label and div?

Comment: I have tried that, but it allways mismatch with label select display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left and right floats on your `.control-label` and `.inline-inputs` classes to easily flip between RTL and LTR mode.

See my quick and dirty JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ub07t7ax/

All it does is toggle between floating the controls right and the labels left, and vice-versa.

Of course you don't have to do this in script, that is just an example.

**Update:** To use this without JS, simply add the `rtl` class to your fieldset in your HTML to enable RTL mode.

Example CSS:

```
.inline-inputs select,
.inline-inputs input,
.inline-inputs textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
.inline-inputs {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
}

.control-label {
    float: left;
    width: 25%
}

.rtl .inline-inputs {
    float: left;
}

.rtl .control-label {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

**UPDATE 2: Bootstrap!**
To work with bootstrap dialogs, first add the following classes to your CSS:

```
.rtl .inline-inputs {
    margin-left: 0 !important;
}

.rtl .control-label {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Then to make the dialog show in RTL mode, add the `rtl` class to the DIV that is shown as a dialog, e.g.

```
<!-- modal edit dialog -->
<div class="modal hide fade rtl" id="timeEntryDetailDialog">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance to use css + html only without JS?

Comment: Sure, the JS is just for the example toggle. You can just assign the rtl class to the fieldset in your HTML. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I now see that the css implement on a bootstarp.min.css file. I have added the code into the original post.

Comment: Well, it is that simple for the question you actually asked, which doesn't mention bootstrap! And where does AngularJS come into it? Can you sort out your tags?

Comment: I just discover that it use bootstrap! I think it is based on angular! See on the link to my live script i have added to the original post.

Comment: Ok, please see my "update 2" which should work with bootstrap dialogs. The CSS is not much different, it just needs to fiddle with margins for the `inline-input` class instead of floating it. You can add the `rtl` class at pretty much any level that is a parent of the other classes, in my example it is on the div that makes the dialog.

Comment: Where do i put the ".rtl .inline-inputs" css lines? In "bootstrap.min.css" or "bootstrap-responsive.min.css" or both? Because it is responsive im not sure where to put it.

Comment: Ideally you would have your own css file for stuff that's unique to your site, rather than customising the bootstrap css. That would make updates hard, but really it doesn't matter where you put the css so long as it's loaded.

Comment: It is not work well. the label now on the right side but not with the same line column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86636/discussion-between-beercohol-and-stackbuck).

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/). This is tutorial for creating HTML Pages in Arabic, Hebrew and Other Right-to-left Scripts.

Comment: I do know all the terms of Right-to-left. But, in this case i kind of gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your CSS I don't know if there is more to it then a simple rearranging of the html (put labels after the div for your inputs) but if not it should just be that. Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WX58z/1238/).

```
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Simple label</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Label with more text</label>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" />
    <label>Short</label>
</div>
```